# How do I get all text from within this tag?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to get all text from within this HTML tag, which I store in variable `tag`:

```
<td rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><a href="/wiki/Glenn_Miller" title="Glenn Miller">Glenn Miller</a> &amp; His Orchestra</td>
```

The result should be `"Glenn Miller & His Orchestra"`.

But `print`ing `tag.find(text=True)` returns this: `"Glenn Miller"`.

How do I get the rest of the text within the `td` element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tag.find(text=True)` would return *the first matching text node*. Use [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) instead:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = '<td rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><a href="/wiki/Glenn_Miller" title="Glenn Miller">Glenn Miller</a> &amp; His Orchestra</td>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
>>> tag = soup.td
>>> tag.get_text()
'Glenn Miller & His Orchestra'
```